# Send an email with an HTML table, with attachment, when a Google Form response is submitted

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a function that runs on an installable "on form submit" trigger. It sends an an email when a form response is submitted.

The Google Form has multiple questions including a question that lets the responder include attachments. I need to send both questions and answers in a table format. The questions should be in bolded in the table. The attachments should be included in the email.

Here's my current code:

```js
function onFormSubmit() {
  var email = "example@gmail.com";
  var subject = "Form Responses";
  var body = "<table>";
  var attachments = [];
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  var lastResponse = responses[responses.length-1];
  var itemResponses = lastResponse.getItemResponses();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    var question = itemResponses[i].getItem().getTitle();
    var response = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
    body += "<tr><td><b>" + question + "</b></td><td>" + response + "</td></tr>";
    
    if (itemResponses[i].getItem().getType() === FormApp.ItemType.FILE_UPLOAD) {
      var fileId = itemResponses[i].getResponse().getId();
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
      attachments.push(file.getBlob());
    }
  }
  body += "</table>";
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, "", {htmlBody: body, attachments: attachments});
}
```

The problem is that the code errors out:

`TypeError: itemResponses[i].getResponse(...).getId is not a function.`

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

`itemResponses[i].getResponse()` is a string not a file.  Try this.

```
let fileId = DriveApp.getFilesByName(itemResponses[i].getResponse()).next().getId();
```

Although I would suggest you use try catch incase a file of that name doesn't exist.